# Can I apply an @EntityGraph to an @Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In the Repository (note: `SELECT_LIST` is just `from Organization org where in ( ... ) and in (...)` ), `IdentifiableWithName` is simply `Persistable` with a `getName()` method, making it a projection.

```
@EntityGraph( Organization.NamedQuery.GRAPH_ID_NAME )
@Query( "select org " + SELECT_LIST + " order by org.name")
List<IdentifiableWithName> findOrganizationsForSelectList();
```

On the entity

```
@NamedEntityGraph( name = Organization.NamedQuery.GRAPH_ID_NAME, attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode( AbstractPersistedEntity.Index.ID  ),
        @NamedAttributeNode( Organization.Index.NAME ) }
)
```

but the resultant queries seem to be the default for the entity and not reduced to just the name, id fields. Is this even possible? if so what am I doing wrong? if this isn't possible with Spring Data is it possible with JPA (meaning could this be a feature request that's feasible)? alternatively is there any other way I can do an `@Query` to a Projection, or the original entity that only includes `id`, and `name` and not any other fields or joins?

Comment: If you found an answer, you can answer your own question too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to Projection in the generic sense and not to Spring Data JPA's specific Projection functionality which should enable you to do what you require:

https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods

> Closed projections allow us to optimize the query execution as only
>   exposed properties are queried from the data store.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections

```
public interface IdentifiableWithName{
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeClass, Long>{
    @Query( "select org " + SELECT_LIST + " order by org.name")
    List<IdentifiableWithName> findOrganizationsForSelectList();
}
```

Comment: no I meant projection as in the spring data term though are we on ... what was in platform 2.0.x... Gosling I think.... was that a new feature? because I tried just IdentifiableWithName (which is an interface, similar to what you have but through inheritance) and it seemed to work, but it wasn't narrowed, it's still basically just querying what the entity type does.